# How to get quarter number in Carbon dates in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, php-carbon

I'm building a graph which has time line as financial quarter so I want to have labels as below:

```
Dates between April-June as Q1
Dates between July-September as Q2
Dates between October-December as Q3
Dates between January-March as Q4
```

For example I have to take previous 6 months labels so right now for months I'm placing label as

```
for($i=0; $i<6; $i++)
{
    $labels[] = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonths($i)->format('M Y');
}
```

How can I achieve this

Comment: What exact output are you looking for?

Comment: @Dev I want labels to be as Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = new Carbon('first day of April');
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
{
    $labels[] = $start->addMonth(3)->format('M Y');
}
```

Maybe like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon's `quarter` method

```
$dt = \Carbon\Carbon::now(); // 5/10/2018 -> is on 2nd quarter of the year
$dt->quarter; // 2 =>  Q2
```

And so you can do

```
for($i=0; $i<6; $i++)
{
    $dt = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonths($i);
    $labels['Q'.$dt->quarter][] = $dt->format('M Y');
}
dd($labels);

// result:
array:3 [▼
  "Q2" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "May 2018"
    1 => "Apr 2018"
  ]
  "Q1" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Mar 2018"
    1 => "Feb 2018"
    2 => "Jan 2018"
  ]
  "Q4" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "Dec 2017"
  ]
]
```